# How can I write scopes that fetches all users who don't have any user_notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :user_notifications
end


class UserNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I am trying to get all the users who **don't** have any user_notifications record yet. Can it be done using scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like developer033's version, but I think you need to use the hash syntax in the `where`:

```
scope :without_notificatons, lambda { 
  eager_load(:user_notifications).where(user_notifications: { user_id: nil }) 
}
```

When you are on Rails 5 already you can use [`left_outer_joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins) what is a bit more readable and explizit.

```
scope :without_notificatons, lambda { 
  left_outer_joins(:user_notifications).where(user_notifications: { user_id: nil }) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @spickermann yes Hash syntax is correct but could you tell me whats the major difference b/w using eager_load and using { joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN user_notifications ON users.id = user_notifications.user_id") answer by sampat

Comment: `eager_load` perfoms a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` behind, you just type less. I like this explanation: http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any project in my front, but since I can remember, you can just do the following:

```
scope :filtered_users, -> { eager_load(:user_notifications).where(user_notifications.user_id: nil) }
```

Answer (score 1):

using SQL in your where statement:

```
scope :no_notifications, -> {includes(:user_notifications).where('NOT EXISTS(select * from user_notifications where user_notifications.user_id = users.id)')}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :user_notifications
 scope :without_notifications, -> { joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN user_notifications ON users.id = user_notifications.user_id").where(user_notifications.id: nil) }
end
```

Comment: It's the same answer as mine... the difference is that I wrote with (`eager_load`) which perfoms also a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.